# 428 connection server connecting to itself

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress website at nepaljapan.com. I recently contacted the server regarding the website load and performance issue. What i got from them was the following response.

"There is 428 connections from IP 166.63.31.176 - which is your server's IP to your server/application. That means that the server tries to reach himself not on localhost but on external ip address which is not good and cause huge load."

When i tried to re consult them they told that it is a code level issue so they cannot help further.

I could not figure out what is causing the issue at the code level as it is a normal wordpress site.

It would be great help if anyone could push me in the right direction?

Comment: You might want to post this on serverfault.com instead, because this question doesn't seem to be about programming.

Comment: What is the value of `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` in your wp-config.php file?

Comment: its defined as localhost